# Access CGI via javascript using the url

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I am currently working on a javascript tool for our business.
Here is the concept of the tool :

1. It's a javascript module that is stored on our server.
2. You can add this tool to your favorite bar and it opens up the module on the right side of your browser.
3. This tool can only be opened if the URL contains our server name. (Example: http://MYSERVERNAME/MYAPPLICATIONSUBFOLDER)

Here is the tricky part I am working on.

4. The tool needs to be able to get the CGI.remote_user variable.

We usually store this variable in a session variable in the onSessionStart method of Application.cfc and use it in our application normally. My Current problem is that I have no idea of how to access the CGI object using only the URL entered in the navigation bar.

Any idea?

Comment: You could make the module make a call to the server for a specific file that returns the required variable and then store it as a JS variable for use later.

Comment: You're looking for AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the javascript module is available only to ColdFusion pages, use ColdFusion to get the variable you need.

```
<script>
var canDoThis = false;
<cfif CGI.remote_user is what you want>
canDoThis = true;
</cfif>
if (canDoThis == true) {
rest of the code
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 ways to go about this.

1. Have coldfusion output javascript. You can call a .cfm file from a script tag same as you would a .js file. Put all the variables you need from the server side into a globally-scoped javascript object have your javascript module call that object. You can also do this inline in the html if you prefer.
2. When the page loads, make an ajax call to the server to get the data you need.